# Is it possible to build a 32 bit plugin for CRM 2011?

Tags: plugins, outlook, 32-bit, dynamics-crm-2011

We have a scenario where we require a plugin to do some custom steps in CRM 2011.

The client PC's are running 32 bit Outlook, due to the requierment for some silverlight applications extending crm, and Silverlight not supporting 64 bit.

Hence the plugins are failing when offline, presumably due to Outlook 32 bit not being able to launch 64bit plugin.   The O/S's are all x64.

I have tried to deploy a 32 bit sampleplugin.dll to the CRM Server, but cannot register it, as I get a BadImageFormatException.

I just want to know if this is possible or not at all ?

I am guessing it's not possible, but just want some confirmation.

Thank, 
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to develop your plugin without a specific target architecture, this means you have to target `Any CPU`.

- Dynamics CRM 2011 is 64 Bit on the server side. The plugin will be therefore executed in 64 Bit processes. That is the reason why you are getting the `BadImageFormatException`
- You could  not be sure, if you have 32 Bit or 64 Bit on the client side

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, are you explicitly targeting x64 when you build the plugins in VS?  If so you might try All CPUs instead.

Comment: Hi,  if I target "Any CPU"  then the plugins register fine on the CRM server (which is X64),   but the plugins fail when running in OUtlook 32bit.